# Fill the "search this view" Fulltextsearch and send the query on the current view

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I want to fill the "search this view" dialog and send it by using lotusscript.

Is that possible and if so, how?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution, but [Windows-only](http://www.proudprogrammer.no/web/ppblog.nsf/d6plinks/GANI-8TUHMF) 
Thanks Robert Ibsen Voith

For activate the Search panel you need to emulate keystrokes: (Alt+V) + E

P.S.: I have not tested this solution.